# Find the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{ \sqrt{7(a+h)}-\sqrt{7a} }{h} $ in terms of $a$ .

Tags: calculus, limits, constants

Find the limit in terms of the constant $a$ :
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{7(a+h)}-\sqrt{7a}}{h}
$$
I have tried to solve this by multiplying the square roots to both sides but i simply can't solve it and i would appreciate some help and guidance .

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not "solving for" a limit, but _evaluating_ a limit. If you have an equation that says something like $\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 2} f(x)\right)^2 - 7\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 2} f(x)\right)+ 8=0$ and you use that to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} f(x)$, then you're _solving for_ the limit. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
You may always multiply by one or add zero and it will not change anything.  Here, let us multiply by $1$ in the form $$\frac{\sqrt{7(a+h)}+\sqrt{7a}}{\sqrt{7(a+h)}+\sqrt{7a}}$$

What happens?

> $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{7(a+h)}-\sqrt{7a}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{7(a+h)}+\sqrt{7a}}{\sqrt{7(a+h)}+\sqrt{7a}} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{7a+7h-7a}{h\left(\sqrt{7(a+h)}+\sqrt{7a}\right)}=\dots$$

Comment: I can cancel out the 7a's on top and i can cancel out the h's?

Comment: And once you've done so, can you then find the limit?  Is there anything stopping you from "plugging in zero for h" at that point?

Comment: The answer that I end up getting is the square root of 7a over 2a

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{7\left(a+h\right)}-\sqrt{7a}}{h}\right)$$
Apply L'Hopital's Rule:

$$\frac{d}{dh}\left(\sqrt{7\left(a+h\right)}-\sqrt{7a}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{a+h}}$$

$$\frac{d}{dh}\left(h\right)=1$$

Then
$$\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{a+h}}}{1}\right) = \lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{a+h}}\right)= \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{a}}$$